# Address of static const isn't const expression?

Tags: c++, static, constant-expression

I though address-of-static was a constant expression as in the example below but I get a compiler error (or is this new to C++0x?)

```
class X {
    static const int x;
    enum { y = &x };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the 1998 standard, 5.19(1):  "In several places, C++ requires expressions that evaluate to an integral or enumeration constant...as enumerator initializers (7.2)...."

Further, "An integral constant-expression can involve only....In particular, except in `sizeof` expressions, functions, class objects, pointers, or references shall not be used...."

Floating literals are explicitly listed as castable to integral or enumeration type, and nothing else is.

Casting even an address constant expression to make an enumerator initializer was invalid from the first standard.

Answer (score 5):

Address of a variable (be it static or non-static) is not a *compile-time* constant. `enum` requires *compile-time* constant. That is why that is giving error.

In fact, GCC gives very clear error message:

> prog.cpp:7: error: ‘X::x’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
>   prog.cpp:7: error: `&' cannot appear in a constant-expression

See yourself : http://ideone.com/FJk3C

---

However, the following is [allowed](http://ideone.com/CX0fi):

```
class X {
    static const int x;
    enum { y = sizeof(x) }; //okay. sizeof(x) can be known at compile time!
};
```

---

Don't confuse compile-time constants with runtime constants. They're two different things.

Comment: $ 5.19.2 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf seems to contradict this.

Comment: @Helltone: That is not contradicting it. Compile-time constants and runtime constants are two different things.

Comment: Read further in 5.19(2).  One of the forbidden things is "a type conversion from a pointer or pointer-to-member type to a literal type".  3.9(10) defines "literal type" as including "scalar type", and "scalar type"s include "arithmetic types".

Answer (score 1):

The program is ill-formed because:

- the address of an object is not a
  integral constant expression
- taking the address of x requires a(n
  out of class) definition
- using a static const integral member anywhere except where an integral
  constant-expression is required requires a definition.

Answer (score 1):

It's a constant expression, but it can't be determined at compile time. The actual value of the address will depend on the region of memory that the executable ends up being loaded to by whatever OS loader is running the thing. Enum members need to have values that can be determined by the compiler.

Cheers,
J.

Answer (score 1):

The address of a static object is a constant expression, but
it's not an integral constant expression, because it doesn't
have an integral type.  And `reinterpret_cast`ing it to an
integral type still doesn't make it an integral constant
expression, since `reinterpret_cast` isn't allowed in integral
constant expressions.  And the initializer for an `enum` value
requires an integral constant expression.

As it stands, of course, the reason you're getting a compiler
error is that you're trying to initialize an `enum` value with
an expression that doesn't have an integral type, and doesn't
have an implicit conversion to an integral type.